# Wordpress bootstrap проблема

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

У меня такая забавная ситуация.Я новичок на Worpdress я index header footer t.d создал и в functions меню создал в header все как list отображается нормально.Bootstrap подключен.Забавно то что bootstrap работает и подключен но готовый nav беру из их сайта не работает нормально. Вот код и скриншот:
1.Это header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <?php wp_head();?>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mahmud</title>
</head>
<?php
if(is_home()):
  $awesome_classes = array('awesome-class');
else:
  $awesome_classes= array('no-awesome-class');
endif;
?>
  <body <?php body_class($awesome_classes); ?>>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary'));?>
```

2.Это index.php

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php
if(have_posts()):

  while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
<h1 >  <?php the_title();?></h1>
<small>Публиковано в:<?php the_time('F j,Y');?> <?php the_time(); ?>,<?php the_category();?> </small>
<p> <?php the_content();?></p>

<?php endwhile;
endif;

  ?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

3.Functions.php:

```
<?php
function awesome_script_enqueue(){
  wp_enqueue_style('awesometheme',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/themestyle.css',array(),'2.0.0','all');
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css',array(),'1.0.0','all');
   wp_enqueue_script('customjs',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js',array(),'2.4.0',true);
 }


 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','awesome_script_enqueue');
function awesome_theme_setup(){

 add_theme_support('menus');

 register_nav_menu('primary','Primary Header Navigation');
 register_nav_menu('footer','Footer Navigation');
}
add_action('init','awesome_theme_setup');
```

4.Footer.php:

```
<footer>
  <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'footer'));?>

</footer>
<?php wp_footer();?>
</body>
</html>
```

5.Скриншот:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы сейчас инспектором посмотрите ваши ссылки, то увидите, что у вас не вся структура меню подтянулась. Скорее всего не хватает обертки для списков и т.д. посмотрите весь список передаваемых аргументов https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

Примерно это выглядит так:

До:

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only"><?php _e( 'Toggle navigation', 'truckage' ); ?></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Truc<span>k</span>age</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <nav class="link-effect-2" id="link-effect-2">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html"><span>Services</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="short-codes.html"><span>Short Codes</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="mail.html"><span>Mail Us</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

После:

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only"><?php _e( 'Toggle navigation', 'truckage' ); ?></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Truc<span>k</span>age</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <?php

                        wp_nav_menu(

                            array(
                                'theme_location'  => 'main_menu',
                                'menu'            => '', 
                                'container'       => 'nav', 
                                'container_class' => 'link-effect-2', 
                                'container_id'    => 'link-effect-2',
                                'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav', 
                                'menu_id'         => '',
                                'echo'            => true,
                                'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                                'before'          => '',
                                'after'           => '',
                                'link_before'     => '',
                                'link_after'      => '',
                                'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                                'depth'           => 0,
                                'walker'          => '',
                            )

                        );

                    ?>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Отлично сработало есть один вопрос есть да навигации многие там вместо <ul><li> это написать да? всегда

Comment: не понял вопроса

Comment: Вот есть например другая навигация там разные стили разные классы т.д можете сказать что к чему тут просто синтаксис вот этого кода я новичок пока что поэтому сложно немного

Comment: Я выше в комментариях давал ссылку, почитайте https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu там все есть. Так же на Youtube можно много чего найти по меню для wordpress если что-то не поймете

Comment: Я посмотрю  если что дам знать  спасибо за труд блогадарен я!